# Adding multiple fields separated by comma into database PHP

Tags: php, mysql, forms, sql-insert

Thank you in advance for any help given! I'm very new to PHP and would love some advice/help! i want many id fields separated by comma to be inputted into a database separately with the same resource id variable.

[Find a link to a picture here! Here, a user enters many ids for the name, and only one ID for the resource, I would like all ids to be entered into the database with the same resource id beside it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HHyq8.png)

```
//so this is creating the array to split up the ids
$array = explode(",", $id);
//finding length of array
$length = count($array);
//now we want to loop through this array, and pass in each variable to the db
for ($x = 0; $x < $length; $x++) {
 $sqlinsert= "INSERT INTO ids_to_resources (id, resource_id) 
    VALUES ($id [$x], $resource_id)"

    $result = mysqli_query($dbcon,$sqlinsert);
}
```

I think it could be something like this code above but it doesnt seem to be working for me...
In short i want a user to enter many ID fields and only one resource field, and for this to be inputed into the database separately. I hope this makes sense! 
Thanks again for any help given!

Answer (score 1):

To only answer your question and not questioning your database schema. Have a look at the following code:

```
$ids = explode(",", $id);
$inserts = array();
foreach ($ids as $id) {
    $inserts[] = "($id,$resource_id)";
}
$query = "INSERT INTO ids_to_resources (id,resource_id) VALUES " . implode(',', $inserts) . ";";
```

You can insert multiple rows in one sql query by seperating them with a comma. The code should generate a query like this:

```
INSERT INTO ids_to_resources (id,resource_id) VALUES (1,4),(2,4),(3,4);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have semicolon after this line and you musnt't have a space between $id and [$x]

```
$sqlinsert= "INSERT INTO ids_to_resources (id, resource_id) 
VALUES ($id[$x], $resource_id)";
```

Answer (score 0):

You would be better off creating a separate table which has a new row for each record... the columns would be ID, NINJA_ID, RESOURCE_ID. Then insert it that way. Put an Index on RESOURCE_ID. This way you can easily search through the database for specific records, updating and deleting would be a lot easier as well.

But if you insist on doing commas,

`$comma_ids = implode("," $array);`